# adding dynamics tabs jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I am using a Jquery tabs component like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="tab">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
  </div>

</div>

 $("#tabs" ).tabs({
      collapsible: true
    });
```

And the title of each tab is loaded from DB (php) like this

```
var mytabs = [<?php  foreach($zersart as $za): ?>{
                     name: "<?php echo $za->art; ?>"},
                 <?php  endforeach; ?>];


    $.each(mytabs, function(indexInArray, myobj) {
          $('#tabs').find('li> a').eq(indexInArray).text(myobj.name);
    });
```

But this method is fix to have a specific number of tabs. I want that the tabs are created according with the number of elements in the array with the title for each tab, I mean, create dynamics tabs. I tried this:

```
$.each(mytabs, function(indexInArray, myobj) {
    $('#tabs').append('<li><a href='+indexInArray+'>'+myobj.name+'</a></li>');
 });
```

And this code was removing the `<li>` components from the `<ul>` in the html. But is not working. How is possible to do this?

Comment: You need to append to 'tab' and not 'tabs'

Comment: THX! @Franco I tried but is still not working

Comment: I don't know if you are passing to the loop the right data in your array. have you tried to 'console.log(myTabs)' to see if contains the correct data? I see you are looping in the array self.

Comment: Hi @Franco yes I did, mytabs has the correct data from the DB. I think the problem is when I create the structure of the tabs. But I don't know where

Comment: Can you post here the output of  your ''mytabs' array so I can see it? I don't think your array is filled correctly in the way you are doing it.

Comment: Looks like this @Franco [{Marc},{John},{Paul}]

Comment: I go to eat now. I will make later a fiddle for you to make this work. A little bit patience... :)

Answer (score 1):

The output of your 'mytabs' array has to be formatted like this:

```
var mytabs = ['Marc','John','Paul']
```

So get rid of this '{' and '}'

Loop then trough the items and add the tabs:

```
$.each(mytabs, function(indexInArray, myobj) {
        console.log(myobj)
        $('#tab').append('<li><a href='+indexInArray+'>'+myobj+'</a></li>');
    });
```

If you need a working example I will make a fiddle for you, but I think you have got the point now. Merry Christmas.

If you find this answer useful please consider to up vote it. This makes easy for other users to find it. Thank you.

**As important note:** I just want let you know that you need also to add the tab contents along with the tabs.